# Is there a simple Python map-reduce framework that uses the regular filesystem?

Tags: python, mapreduce

I have a few problems which may apply well to the Map-Reduce model. I'd like to experiment with implementing them, but at this stage I don't want to go to the trouble of installing a heavyweight system like Hadoop or Disco.

Is there a lightweight Python framework for map-reduce which uses the regular filesystem for input, temporary files, and output?

Comment: Okay, I'm finding great stuff by googling "python map-reduce", so one point for obviousness. Check out [Parallel MapReduce in Python](http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) which uses the the builtin python `map` and `reduce` functions with multiprocessing pools. I guess since map and reduce are already there, its another point for obviousness!

Comment: you might find pydoop useful. http://pydoop.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html

Comment: @tdelaney, I know there are lots of results. The reason I asked here is to see what actual people have used with decent results. SO isn't just for things that are un-googleable.

Comment: @tariq, "Pydoop is a package that provides a Python API for Hadoop." I'd like to avoid Hadoop since it has a lot of overhead and you have to deal with HDFS.

Comment: yeas. you are right. since the java API allows us to work with local FS quite well, i thought pydoop will also be capable of doing that. my python knowledge is limited to just "hello word", so apologies from my side if pydoop doesn't serve the purpose. perhaps you could give it a try to check it for yourself :)

Comment: Disco Project is pure python distributed Map/Reduce framwork
http://discoproject.org/

Answer (score 11):

A Coursera course dedicated to big data suggests using these lightweight python Map-Reduce frameworks:

- http://code.google.com/p/octopy/
- https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy

To get you started very quickly, try this example:

https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy/zipball/v0.1.2

(hint: for [server address] in this example use localhost)

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/bigdata?from_restricted_preview=1&course_id=970315&r=https%3A%2F%2Fclass.coursera.org%2Fbigdata-002%2Fclass

Answer (score 6):

http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/ is great to quickly get started on your local machine, basically all you need is a simple:

pip install mrjob

Comment: This should be the right answer. Not only it lets you work on your local files, which covers playing and learning with MR, but it lets you do so in a transparent and uniform manner **also** on AWS hadoop solution (EMR) and your local hadoop cluster. https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob

Comment: But when running MRJob locally, it doesn't seem to run tasks in parallel. Or does it?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsmapreduce.com/  -- in-browser mapreduce; in Python or Javascript; nothing to install

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Apache Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/). It is written in Java but it has also a Python API. You can try it locally on your machine and then, when you need it, you can easily distribute your computation over a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

MockMR - https://github.com/sjtrny/mockmr

It's meant for educational use. Does not currently operate in parallel but accepts standard Python objects as IO.

Answer (score 0):

So this was asked ages ago, but I worked on a full implementation of mapreduce over the weekend: remap.

https://github.com/gtoonstra/remap

Pretty easy to install with minimal dependencies, if all goes well you should be able to run a test run in 5 minutes.

The entire processing pipeline works, but submitting and monitoring jobs is still being worked on.